# Animation breaks when applying modifiers

Tags: animation

I have made a conveyor belt model with an animation and I need to export it to Unity. Its animation only works when the array and curve modifiers aren't applied.
Video: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEkCk.jpg

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, modifiers except armature doesn't support by Unity and FBX. Try to add armature, and animate it instead using modifiers.

This is an example of the technique: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFN4F9dmpIQ&ab_channel=RNG

Alternatively, you can export one segment and build an animation using C# code or search for Unity prefabs in Unity marketplace.